# Frames aren't written to video using opencv

Tags: opencv, video, frames

I'm trying to create a program that exports frames into a video file.
I'm using C.

I have an array of IplImage* (IplImage** images) which contains all the frames that I want to export into a video.
However, the video that comes out is always blank (with no frames and the duration is 0:00).
Here is the part of my code thta I think I made wrong (size is the size of the images array):

```
CvVideoWriter* vWriter = cvCreateVideoWriter(path, CV_FOURCC('N', 'A', 'V', 'I'), 50, cvSize(maxWidth, maxHeight), 1);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cvWriteFrame(vWriter, images[i]);
}
cvReleaseVideoWriter(&vWriter);
free(images);
```

The video that is created is empty, instead of having all of the frames of the array IplImage** images in it

Edit: It's kind of an assigment (more like a bonus), and I have to user C.
If I use c++ it doesn't count.

Comment: Out of curiosity, any particular reason you're using the C version of opencv and not the C++ version? the C++ version has the cv::Mat class that makes it very convenient for processing.

Comment: The C API has also been deprecated for a decade now. Please don't write new code using it.

Comment: It's kind of an assigment, so I have to do it in C.

Comment: try different codecs. does it work with MJPG?

Comment: You were right. I have changed the codec to  MJPG, and now it works better. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for everyone for all the help!

Comment: It works now, thank you all